Is there a specific name for inverted Taylor series?
Is there a specific name for inverted Taylor series?
$$f(x)=f(a)+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n+1} (x-a)^n f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}$$
Is it applicable anywhere?
It can be obtained from Taylor series by swapping the expansion point and the free variable.

So you know all the derivatives at $x$ but not the actual value?

@Henry yes, this expresses the value via derivatives.

It's called Lagrange series.
